# Add currency symbols to `TextBlock`

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app where I just need to show currency Symbol in a textBlock either in `XAML` or via programmatically. To obtain such I've to use `Unicode Characters`.
But while using this statement

```
    <TextBlock Text="&#xf01;"/> //I Got some characters but using
    <TextBlock Text="&#xf001;"/> //I got a square box
    //Note: &#xf001; or &#xf01; is not a currency symbol
```

So my question is how to add currency Symbol like `$` `Yen`,`Indian Rupee`, etc. using XAML or C#, I tried a lot so far but do not get success. Any answer will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I was using wrong format of Currency Code.
Here is the list of [Currency Code](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf).

Correct format to use the currency symbol is

```
   <TextBlock Text="&#x20b9;"/> //for Indian Currency
```

Still thanks for your valuable answers, but just now I found this and its working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `StringFormat` on you binding to show a value as currency

Example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C}" />
```

And you can specify the `ConverterCulture` to show $ Yen,Indian Rupee

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=de-DE}" />
```

Comment: Is this possible for all? like if I want to create a list of currencies where I have to show their symbol. If I define the culture manually here then I don't think that It will work for all. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try using images or XAML Path Button Style.

Check out [Syncfusion's Metro Studio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio).

The end result could be an image that you call according to the currency or an style where you can change it dynamically.

Add this to MainPage.xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>



    <Style x:Key="PathBasedAppBarButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Width="18" Height="18" 
             Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0 0 2 0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
             Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
             Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="RupeeAppBarButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PathBasedAppBarButtonStyle}" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Rupee"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="RupeeAppBarButton"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="F1M379.388,262.844L409.946,262.844C410.118,262.867,410.203,262.953,410.203,263.104L410.203,266.01C410.203,266.183,410.118,266.269,409.946,266.269L398.446,266.269 398.446,266.527C400.083,267.411,401.354,269.219,402.258,271.954L402.387,272.891 409.946,272.891C410.118,272.912,410.203,272.998,410.203,273.149L410.203,276.055C410.203,276.229,410.118,276.314,409.946,276.314L402.677,276.314C402.677,279.566 400.686,282.732 396.702,285.811 393.17,287.836 390.662,288.848 389.175,288.848 389.175,288.934 389.09,288.977 388.918,288.977L405.326,310.231 405.326,310.49 399.093,310.49C399.028,310.49,392.685,302.264,380.067,285.811L380.067,285.682 382.037,285.682C389.014,285.682 393.202,283.174 394.602,278.156 394.688,277.553 394.731,277.069 394.731,276.702L394.731,276.314 379.388,276.314C379.216,276.314,379.13,276.229,379.13,276.055L379.13,273.149C379.151,272.977,379.237,272.891,379.388,272.891L394.602,272.891C394.086,270.932 392.987,269.337 391.308,268.11 388.981,266.882 386.861,266.269 384.944,266.269L379.388,266.269C379.216,266.269,379.13,266.183,379.13,266.01L379.13,263.104C379.151,262.931,379.237,262.844,379.388,262.844z"/>
    </Style>





    <Style x:Key="YenAppBarButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PathBasedAppBarButtonStyle}" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Yen"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="YenAppBarButton"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="F1M304.401,-42.8347L304.401,-55.4694 293.272,-55.4694 293.272,-58.9883 304.401,-58.9883 304.401,-64.2292 293.272,-64.2292 293.272,-67.7468 302.678,-67.7468 290.544,-89.5013 297.293,-89.5013 304.759,-74.7116C305.909,-72.2695,306.77,-70.3314,307.631,-68.1777L307.847,-68.1777C308.564,-70.1882,309.498,-72.4134,310.718,-74.8548L318.472,-89.5013 325.078,-89.5013 312.226,-67.7468 321.56,-67.7468 321.56,-64.2292 310.36,-64.2292 310.36,-58.9883 321.56,-58.9883 321.56,-55.4694 310.36,-55.4694 310.36,-42.8347 304.401,-42.8347z"/>
    </Style>




    <Style x:Key="DollarAppBarButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource PathBasedAppBarButtonStyle}" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Dollar"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="DollarAppBarButton"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="F1M183.025,3329.47L183.025,3337.06 177.917,3337.06 177.917,3329.68C173.181,3329.66,168.773,3328.59,164.689,3326.46L164.689,3316.77C166.044,3317.87 168.062,3318.88 170.744,3319.82 173.427,3320.75 175.818,3321.28 177.917,3321.42L177.917,3308.69C172.458,3306.66 168.732,3304.46 166.737,3302.09 164.742,3299.72 163.745,3296.84 163.745,3293.43 163.745,3289.77 165.039,3286.65 167.63,3284.07 170.219,3281.49 173.648,3279.99 177.917,3279.57L177.917,3273.07 183.025,3273.07 183.025,3279.43C187.947,3279.67,191.622,3280.46,194.048,3281.81L194.048,3291.26C190.782,3289.28,187.109,3288.06,183.025,3287.62L183.025,3300.88C188.135,3302.73 191.797,3304.83 194.012,3307.2 196.228,3309.57 197.337,3312.43 197.337,3315.79 197.337,3319.66 196.102,3322.78 193.63,3325.15 191.155,3327.52 187.622,3328.96 183.025,3329.47z M177.917,3298.85L177.917,3287.76C174.673,3288.35 173.054,3290.04 173.054,3292.84 173.054,3295.24 174.673,3297.24 177.917,3298.85z M183.025,3310.68L183.025,3321.28C186.361,3320.77 188.031,3319.1 188.031,3316.28 188.031,3313.99 186.361,3312.13 183.025,3310.68z"/>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

And you can change the style dynamically:

```
button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["DefaultMusicButtonStyle"];
```

Comment: I like your suggestion dude, thanks :) as they are not part of the question I can not accept it as answer, my question was clear about using `Unicode Characters`. But I really like your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get `CultureInfo` for the country and then use `NumberFormatInfo` to get `currency symbol`:

```
// Display the culture name and currency symbol.
NumberFormatInfo nfi = ci.NumberFormat;
sb.AppendFormat("The currency symbol for '{0}' is '{1}'",
ci.DisplayName, nfi.CurrencySymbol);
sb.AppendLine();
```

Comment: You mean I should fetch the Culture Info from device and then set its value like this? If so, I'm sorry but I've to do this for all Currencies as I've to make a list.

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting getting current culture info. You can get list of all culures by calling  GetCultures method of Cultureinfo class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx and then add them to a list. If you do that you wouldn't need to mantain a static list of currensy symbols

Comment: OK let me try it. will let you know soon.

Comment: Sorry, Its not working for Windows Phone 8 Its only Support Windows 8 and others